# Can a Betazoid read a Trill symbiont's mind?

Tags: star-trek, betazoid

Could a Betazoid (skilled or otherwise) read the feelings or thoughts of a Trill symbiont? Is there any evidence in the canon that this is possible?

Comment: There are only three DS9 episodes with Lwaxana in them, and I'm pretty sure any evidence would have to be in one of them or in "The Host" (which the current answer already discusses). Lwaxana can definitely project emotions onto Jadzia Dax — this happens in both "Fascination" and "The Muse". I don't think there's any evidence of receptive telepathy in either case, and anyway it could always be Jadzia's mind she's affecting. In the third episode ("The Forsaken") they basically don't interact at all.

Comment: Worth mentioning that Trill host-symbiote physiology was rewritten between TNG and DS9- what might have been true in *the Host* concerning telepaths and symbiotes might not be in Ds9 or other shows.

Answer (score 8):

TNG S4E23 *The Host* has this dialogue:

> PICARD: Counsellor, what is it?
>   TROI: It's Ambassador Odan. **I continually feel fluctuations of emotion from him.**
>   PICARD: Perhaps it's perfectly normal among the Trill.
>   TROI: It could be. We know so very little about them.
>   PICARD: Yes. Quite.

Unfortunately she says little else about him, but this does make it clear that (half-Betazoid) Counsellor Troi can at least partially feel the emotions of (Trill) Ambassador Odan, so **the Trill are not completely immune to Betazoid empathic abilities**.

Comment: This is a good, relevant piece of dialogue (so +1).  But I should point out the question is asking about the *symbiont* (not the host), where as the dialogue above, at least as presented, doesn't distinguish between the host and symbiont.  Perhaps some context from surrounding dialogue will help to clear it up.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any context that would make it clear whether she's feeling the host's or the symbiote's emotions (when this quote happens no one even knows the Trill are a race of symbiotes yet). The strongest argument I can think of on that point is that nobody mentions the host's thoughts or feelings once during the entire episode, but that doesn't feel solid enough to put in an answer.

Comment: @Praxis I don't have specific references right now but I believe it was often implied, possibly explicitly stated (been a while since I watched DS9) that the host + symbiont pair was basically one being with a unique new personality that was a combination of the new host, past hosts, and symbiont. It's entirely possible that there *is* no distinction between the host's and symbiont's thoughts after their union develops fully (takes 72 hours or so IIRC). So it may not even make sense to ask if their minds can be read separately. Troi seems to be just as unclear on the details as we are.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't think that a Betazoid would have trouble reading a Trill---they are "typical" humanoids, after all. The symbiont is another story. Though didn't Troi sense that Nagilum was a very powerful mind? Didn't she partially read Armus? If she could read these non-humanoids, maybe a Trill symbiont would be child's play in comparison.